# How do I clear my name when wrongfully accused of cheating?

Tags: cheating

I'm pursing an online engineering degree at ASU. In a introduction circuit class, I have a flimsy idea of what I'm doing and little time (each class is only 7 weeks long) to try to figure it out, so for some assignments I take my best guess and my mentality is if I miss some points, so be it, as long as I understand the gist that's being asked.

This class had a relatively huge project where we submitted photos and the program files for 2 related circuit designs and it was broken down into 3 parts, 1 part for all of the lab information, 1 part for the first program file for the first design and 1 part for the second program file. When it came to the lab part, I had a good idea of what was asked and by the end I thought I knew what I was doing.

For the 2 program files of the circuit designs I tried making similar circuits to those that were in examples in lecture videos for my class, but they didn't work correctly. So instead, I researched using a YouTube video by the TA in my class, a tutorial about the type of circuits being made and a powerpoint from a different university. I did NOT copy a single design presented in the video, tutorial or powerpoint. I re-checked and I can guarantee that my design does not look exactly like any of the ones viewed in the learning materials I used. Instead, I took components from each of the designs until I had something that produced the logic I theoretically proved it could be in the lab report.

I received an email from the TA asking why I submitted an entirely different project than what was being asked, and my only simple answer is that I had no idea what I was doing. Obviously, that isn't a good enough answer when someone is implying you cheated. So in a long response email I explained that I didn't feel confident in what I was doing and I tried to make something that worked and I explained how I did each part of the project and linked him the learning materials I used.

He hasn't responded, but I would like to know if anyone knows, is there anything I can in a situation like this where it's implied that I cheated and even though I most definitely have not, I can't prove that I didn't given the learning environment? What can I do?

Comment: To clarify, apparently the designs I did end up making are something required in a project for a class higher above mine and the TA is implying I cheated because I turned in what's required for their assignment for our class. With this in mind, I have no way to know people in other classes because this is an online environment and personally, I would never go out of my way to socialize with people I don't have to.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is cheating so much as failing to demonstrate that you had learned the material the assignment was supposed to solidify and test.

Comment: How did you get from "TA asking why I submitted an entirely different project than what was being asked" to "implying you cheated" ?

Comment: There's nothing I can do there then, because I obviously haven't learned the material. I haven't been confident in any of the assignments I've turned in and I've been going off the grades I get as feedback to know if I'm actually understanding the material at all.

The way the TA worded his email was phrased, "why did you turn in the project meant for a class you're not enrolled in?" As someone who's in their first semester at this university and has no prior background on this material, I'm not sure how else I'm supposed to take that.

Comment: There's nothing you have to do, unless the TA actually accuses you of cheating. But he didn't, as far as we understand. It could be that your long answer how you ended up in this situation was enough to show him what happened. If nothing happens, nothing happened.

Comment: _I took components from each of the designs_ — So perhaps you _did_ cheat after all.

Answer (score 32):

> How do I clear my name when wrongfully accused of cheating?

Putting myself in the shoes of the TA, I would say that you haven't even been accused of cheating.

You say:

> I received an email from the TA asking ***why I submitted an entirely different project than what was being asked***, and my only simple answer is that I had no idea what I was doing. Obviously, that isn't a good enough answer when someone is implying you cheated.

The answer is right there: Your TA asked you why you submitted an entirely different project than the one you were supposed to complete and you said you didn't know what you were doing, which, by the way, completely confirms your TA's suspicions (i.e., that a clueless student completed a project in one of the most completely incorrect ways).

TL;DR: I wouldn't worry about the cheating "accusation."

<sup>(but do worry about whether you are putting your best foot forward with respect to completing course assignments and projects the way they're intended to be completed, etc.)</sup>

Comment: On the other hand, if I ask for a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra and you provide a complete, correct proof of the lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, I may very well suspect you cheated. The implication being that someone who has trouble understanding the very question is unlikely to present a perfect solution to another problem of similar (or superior) complexity, and must have copied something from somewhere without even realising it was the wrong thing to copy. Not saying that is the case, but it does raise some concern

Comment: @Ant: This happens all the time in computer science. Solving a much harder problem often results in the simpler problem as a special case of it.

Comment: @Ant Sure, good point. In this case, I may tell the student something along the lines of "there is no way you could've solved this problem when you couldn't solve _that_ problem, and for the [more complicated project coming soon] I'll be sure to scrutinize your work more heavily at that time to ensure that the work is your own." I don't see any way to pursue an academic dishonesty claim in the case that the OP describes, though.

Answer (score 11):

I think the TA was rightly concerned about an entirely different issue from cheating. I have done only a little bit of circuit design, but a lot of programming and they have some similarities. I believe doing exercises, in both cases, makes the difference between vaguely getting the gist of an idea, and solidly understanding it.

You were given an assignment that was supposed to help you solidify specific knowledge so that you could apply it, and to demonstrate your understanding to the instructors. You did not understand the material well enough to do the assignment as set.

At that point the right course of action would be to go to office hours or contact the TA to get help understanding the material, and work at it until you could apply it to the exercise. If you had to guess on any earlier assignments for the same or prerequisite courses, you should go back and review the material for those assignments.

Instead, you turned in material that might have been a good answer to a different question for a different course, but did not demonstrate understanding of the material for your current course.

You are probably going to get a low grade for the assignment, not because of cheating but because of failing to do the assignment as set, and failing to understand the material the course is intended to communicate.

---

For the sake of your understanding of future courses, you would probably benefit from taking another shot at doing the assignment, even if it is too late to get it graded. The better you understand the year one material, the less difficulty you will have next year.